# lz4 command outputs to stdout unexpectedly

Tags: bash

Using this lz4 command:

```
$ apt search ^lz4$
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
lz4/focal,now 1.9.2-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Fast LZ compression algorithm library - tool

$ lz4 --version
*** LZ4 command line interface 64-bits v1.9.2, by Yann Collet ***
```

This command normally creates a `filename.lz4` file (just like gzip does):

```
$ lz4 -9 -k filename
```

However, this command does not, and instead writes to stdout when I'm not telling it to:

```
$ t=$(lz4 -9 -k filename)
Warning : using stdout as default output. Do not rely on this behavior: use explicit `-c` instead ! 
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

Why is it doing this? Is it a bug, or is there a reason documented somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour appears to be a feature - not a bug. I can't find it documented anywhere except in the [source code](https://sources.debian.org/src/lz4/1.9.3-1/programs/lz4cli.c/?hl=559#L674):

```
/* No output filename ==> try to select one automatically (when possible) */
while ((!output_filename) && (multiple_inputs==0)) {
    if (!IS_CONSOLE(stdout)) {
        /* Default to stdout whenever stdout is not the console.
         * Note : this policy may change in the future, therefore don't rely on it !
         * To ensure `stdout` is explicitly selected, use `-c` command flag.
         * Conversely, to ensure output will not become `stdout`, use `-m` command flag */
        DISPLAYLEVEL(1, "Warning : using stdout as default output. Do not rely on this behavior: use explicit `-c` instead ! \n");
        output_filename=stdoutmark;
        break;
        .
        .
}
```

On Linux, `IS_CONSOLE` uses `isatty` to determine whether file desscriptors are connected to a terminal.

As suggested in the comment, you can use the `-m` option to force generation of an output file in cases where there is no tty:

```
t=$(lz4 -9 -k -m filename)
```

Comment: Thanks, good investigation and outcome.